# Convert list of coordinates to list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a python script that generates a list of coordinates in the following format.

```
[([-37.9503756], [176.93828736155422]),
 ([-43.6131375], [172.3051281]),
 ([-38.1272259], [177.1307049])]
```

I want to convert that to the following format.

```
list_of_coords = [(-37.9503756, 176.93828736155422), (-43.6131375, 172.3051281), (-38.1272259, 177.1307049)]
```

I tried to convert the list to a nested list and convert it to list of tuple. But, it didn't work.

```
listoflist = [list(row) for row in list_of_coords]
listoflist

[[[-37.9503756], [176.93828736155422]],
 [[-43.6131375], [172.3051281]],
 [[-38.1272259], [177.1307049]]]

list(map(tuple, listoflist))

[([-37.9503756], [176.93828736155422]),
 ([-43.6131375], [172.3051281]),
 ([-38.1272259], [177.1307049])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done using a simple list comprehension:

```
[(x[0][0], x[1][0]) for x in items]
```

Comment: Using tuple unpacking: `[(x,y) for [[x],[y]] in items]`